# Worklight SQL Adapter - can't pass a param to IN clause

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

i want to pass a list of values as a string to an IN clause in my Worklight 6.1 SQL Adapter:

```
SQL_Query= select * from USERS where name in (?);
```

i pass the following string as a param:

```
'john','mike','joe'
```

The call to the SQL procedure failed with the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
```

So my question is: how to deal with IN params in a SQL Adapter?

Comment: try `SQL_Query= select * from USERS where name in (?,?,?);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point was to use a length-variable parameter, as i don't know how many people to retrieve (the number depends on context).

Actually, it's not possible to do such with a PreparedStatement (JDBC). It can only be used with a Statement. Unfortunately, Worklight API does not propose statement but only preparedstatement.

The following is working, but i have to limit my search to 3 people:

```
SQL_Query= select * from USERS where name in (?,?,?);
```

or (dirty):

```
SQL_Query= select * from USERS where name = ? or name = ? or name = ?;
```